# Getting all data from last month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I am building an SQL view which shows me all entries of table T where the information is last month. I want it so that if I run the view any time in August, it will show me all entries for July, not just a month before which is what I have done with my current code.

Please see this:

```
where cast(t.Ticket_OpenDate as date) >= cast(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) as date)
```

I look forward to hearing from someone.

Comment: Please tag the question with your DBMS.

Comment: @buddemat I have tagged it as TSQL however it is also through Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Comment: This may help:  
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cae69ca2-7ada-4eab-9527-7748bf4ab57b/getdate-get-previous-month-data?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `DATEDIFF` as in the other answer will not perform well because it cannot use indexes (it is not [sarge-able](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates)).**

It is much better to use a date interval (start and end), in this case we want a half-open interval (exclusive end date):

```sql
WHERE t.Ticket_OpenDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1, 1)
  AND t.Ticket_OpenDate <  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE())    , 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `DATEDIFF()` function for that:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, CAST(t.Ticket_OpenDate as date), GETDATE()) = 1
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2604890454b2932ccab1fe32e642a3e8) for an example.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.